# How to use libsvm for classification in python

Tags: python, testing, libsvm

I am a novice about svm classification but i have learned some basic theory behind svm classification.

But i would like to know the code in python 2.7 for defining,training and testing of a problem in which each feature vector contain 20 elements.

Can anyone explain how can i use libsvm with a simple example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214868/an-example-using-python-bindings-for-svm-library-libsvm